# Hybris exclude Smart Edit grunt from compilation

Tags: sap-commerce-cloud, smartedit

Is there any way to exclude smart edit grunt rush compile from ant build process? This grunt process adds almost 2 extra minutes to ant build compilation to finish.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The rush build is triggered inside `smartedittools` extension so it will exeute even if you don't have an addon installed in your storefront or if you don't have a storefront at all (e.g. when using decoupled frontend like Spartacus)

You can use `smartedittools.only.build.once=true` flag to tell it to build only once, see comment in `smartedittools/project.properties`:

```
# Introduce new flag to skip smartedit build if bundle files(smartedit/apps/smartedit-master/dist/**) already generated.
# Smartedit dev team: Will keep value false by default since Rush incremental build working fine under git working tree.
# Other hybris team and Non-Smartedit partner: Use true to avoid build smartedit everytime in commerce-suite.zip env.
# Smartedit partner: Update the value on-demand, delete the smartedit bundle or change flag to true will build again.
smartedittools.only.build.once=false
```

Answer (score 1):

1. Remove the following directory:

   hybris/bin/modules/npm-ancillary/npmancillary/resources/npm/node_modules
2. Uninstall the addon using the `ant addonunistall` command (optional, because uninstalling the addon without removing the aforementioned folder won't reduce the build time, but, in my opinion, is better to uninstall it, so the developers working on the project won't be confused):

   ant addonuninstall -Daddonnames=smarteditaddon -DaddonStorefront.yacceleratorstorefront=yourstorefront

Answer (score 0):

As you are aware from which build.xml macro is getting called, so please comment that macro entry in same build.xml and place in config-->customize directory[it should follow same directory structure of original file]

then run :

```
ant customize and ant clean all
```

Comment: The problem is that the build.xml located in hybris/bin/platform doesn't even mention SmartEdit so I can't comment that macro entry.